# The text is pushed down when there is a picture in the other column

Tags: beamer, graphics, columns

In this document:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{MWE}
\begin{columns}[t]

\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{block}{block}
    abc
\end{block}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=.9 \textwidth]{image.png}
\end{column}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

the text "abc" appears lower than the image. It should be next to it in the same height - that's what columns are for! Is this a bug?

Comment: When the [t] option is removed, the text "abc'' is aligned to the image!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the beamer user guide section 12.7:

> - t will cause the first lines of the columns to be aligned. Default if global option t is used.
> - T is similar to the t option, but T aligns the tops of the first lines while t aligns the so-called baselines of the first lines. If strange things seem to happen in conjunction with the t option (for example if a graphic suddenly “drops down” with the t option instead of “going up,”), try using this option instead.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{MWE}
\begin{columns}[T]

\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{block}{block}
    abc
\end{block}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=.9 \textwidth]{example-image.png}
\end{column}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]